# echo-printing the data that comes back from YQL

Tags: yql, qooxdoo

In [the qooxdoo playground](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/playground) there is a YQL binding sample. I want to see what data comes back from querying the URL.

How can I modify this code:

```
var delegate = {manipulateData : function(data) {

  return data.query.results.item;
}};
```

so that I can view the return data? I've tried `this.debug(data)` and pressing F7 but I dont see any data there.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're inside an object the keyword `this` points to the object itself.

So you either have to use:

- `qx.log.Logger.debug(data)` in order to print into the Log area of the playground (and the browser console)
- or just use `console.log(data)` and inspect the object solely within your browser console.

So it would look like this:

```
var delegate = {manipulateData : function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  return data.query.results.item;
}};
```

Comment: `console.log(data)` does nothing on IE6. `qx.log.Logger.debug(data)` yields `11289610 {query:{...(4)}}` ... so how do I get it to show the data structure in detail? Granted in this case, I can simply go to the yql page and play with their testbed, but I really want to know how to do this in general when such resources are not available.

Comment: IE6 is unfortunately your worst browser choice :(. I recommend you to try for example [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/fx/).

Comment: Anyway, if you use `qx.log.Logger.debug(data).query` you see more in the Log area. But this will be tedious because you can't "browse" the object like in a browser console. If you are only interested in the result of the YQL query, then maybe the [YQL Console](http://y.ahoo.it/W7EvQ) is for you. You have to switch to 'JSON', remove the 'cbfunc' and then hit 'Test'. This should be the same object which you get in the playground sample.